# Encryption-decryption method

Tags: php, algorithm, security

### My encryption algorithm

I'm using this algorithm in order to encrypt notes users save on my site:

```
  function CasualPassword($lenght=527){
    $available_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; 
    $password = ""; 
    for($i = 0; $i<$lenght; $i++){
        $password .= substr($available_chars,rand(0,strlen($available_chars)-1),1);
    } 
    return $password; 
  }
$key = CasualPassword();
$string = nl2br($_POST['nota']);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++ ) {
   $temp = $string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)];
   $crypt .= str_pad( dechex( ord( $temp ) ), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
$encryptednote = $key.'__'.$crypt;
```

So if I encrypted "Code review is awesome" I'd get something like this:

> 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__002d5d24124731440e571c473a1e45343611351a5b0d

Or this:

> 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__751c055c6a37343e19281a561e12502c3b3023033b2e

### My decryption algorithm

```
$separate = explode("__",$encryptednote);
$key =$separate[0];
$crypt = $separate[1];
$cnt = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen( $crypt ); $i+=2){
    $temp = chr( hexdec( substr( $crypt, $i, 2) ) );
    $string .= $temp ^ $key[$cnt % strlen($key)];
    $cnt++;
}
```

### Complete code

```
<?php
include("../co.php");
include("config.php");
if($_GET['del']!="" and is_numeric($_GET['del'])){
  $user = addslashes($_SESSION['user']);
  $drop = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='".$_GET['del']."' and username='".$user."'";
mysqli_query($connect,$drop);
$_SESSION['download']="0";
$_SESSION['downloaded']="";
echo '<script>
$("#princ").html("Note deleted.");
 $("#princ").load("../includes/note.php", function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#princ").html("An error occurred");
   }
});
  setTimeout(function() {
$("#note").load("../includes/note.php?load=true", function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#princ").html("An error occurred");
   }
});
}, 10000);
 </script>';
die();
}
if($_POST['nota']!=""){//critta e inserisci nel db
  function CasualPassword($lenght=527){
    $available_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; 
    $password = ""; 
    for($i = 0; $i<$lenght; $i++){
        $password .= substr($available_chars,rand(0,strlen($available_chars)-1),1);
    } 
    return $password; 
  }
$key = CasualPassword();
$string = nl2br($_POST['nota']);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++ ) {
   $temp = $string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)];
   $crypt .= str_pad( dechex( ord( $temp ) ), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
$encryptednote = $key.'__'.$crypt;
$query = "INSERT INTO  `notes` (
`username` ,
`nota`
)
VALUES (
'$user',  '$encryptednote'
);";
mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$_SESSION['download']="0";
$_SESSION['downloaded']="";
echo '<script>
 $("#note").html("Loading...");
 $("#note").load("../includes/note.php?load=true", function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#princ").html("An error occurred.");
   }
});
 function update() {
  $.get("../includes/note.php?load=true", function(data) {
    $("#note").html(data);
  });
}
window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
 </script>';
}
else if($_POST['nota']=="" and $_GET['load']==""){echo '<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#go").click(function(){
  $("#note").html("Please wait...");
$.ajax({
url:"../includes/note.php",
type: "POST",
data: $("#notes").serialize(),
   success: function(msg)
      {
        $("#note").html(msg);
      },
      error: function()
      {
        alert("Error!");
      }
    });
  });
});
 $("#note").html("Loading...");
 $("#note").load("../includes/note.php?load=true", function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#princ").html("An error occurred.");
   }
});
function update() {
  $.get("../includes/note.php?load=true", function(data) {
    $("#note").html(data);
  });
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="../includes/note.php" id="notes">
<textarea name="nota" id="nota" style="width:100%; height:20%;"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="go" value="Save">
</form>';}
if($_GET['load']=="true"){echo '<h3>Your notes</h3>';
//seleziona tutte le note
  $user = addslashes($_SESSION['user']);
  $download = addslashes($_SESSION['download']);
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE username='".$user."' AND id>'".$download."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,50");
while($note = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$separate = explode("__",$encryptednote);
$key =$separate[0];
$crypt = $separate[1];
$cnt = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen( $crypt ); $i+=2){
    $temp = chr( hexdec( substr( $crypt, $i, 2) ) );
    $string .= $temp ^ $key[$cnt % strlen($key)];
    $cnt++;
}
echo $string.'<br><button class="opzione" id="elimina'.$note['id'].'" onclick="$(\'#elimina'.$note['id'].'\').hide(); $(\'#confermaz'.$note['id'].'\').show();">Delete</button><button class="opzione" id="confermaz'.$note['id'].'" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:apriLink(\'../includes/note.php?del='.$note['id'].'\')">Confirm</a></button><hr>';
if($note['id']>$_SESSION['download'] or $_SESSION['download']==""){$_SESSION['download']=$note['id'];}
$_SESSION['downloaded'] .= $stringa.'<br><button class="opzione" id="elimina'.$note['id'].'" onclick="$(\'#elimina'.$note['id'].'\').hide(); $(\'#confermaz'.$note['id'].'\').show();">Delete</button><button class="opzione" id="confermaz'.$note['id'].'" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:apriLink(\'../includes/note.php?del='.$note['id'].'\')">Confirm</a></button><hr>';
$stringa="";
}
echo $_SESSION['downloaded'];
echo '<script>
window.setTimeout(update, 3000); </script>';
die();
}
?>
<div id="note"></div>
```

### My question

Is this method to encrypt/decrypt a string safe?

Comment: Could you please include the complete code? As your code is in italian, it is hard to read without function declarations and an example on how those functions are called. And to answer your question: [most likely it is not safe](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own). It's always good to program things yourself to learn, but for a live site, I would suggest existing solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I translated variable names into English, anyway I'm posting the complete code (just the time to translate it too).
Could you give me some examples of encryption algorithms that I could use?

Comment: Wow, looking at your revised question after posting my answer has made my brain wobble! SQL INJECTION ALERT! NOT SAFE CODE! never trust user inputted variables see Tim's post for more info.

Comment: The problem here is that this sort of code is what you usually get back from google when searching for MySQLi code / wrappers. I started off coding using similar practices, very unsafe

Comment: @CodeX Yeah, I didn't know that addslashes() wasn't enough sure and that XSS attacks could affect other users than the one who saved the note (which should be private, so I thought nobody could be attacked by running a code of an other user); the deletion query was secured with is_numeric, and the user session could only be alphanumeric. To be honest (really), this code is one of my first that I've done all by myself some time ago, but I had never thought (but looks like I should have) of improving it until now. Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: Consider sending a $token with your AJAX request, generate the $token using a good method and store it in a session for comparison later on, if the tokens don't match then the request has likely come from an outside source

Comment: @CodeX I'll do that for sure, thanks very much for your precious help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Security

**Encryption**

This is not secure.

You are sending out the **key** with the **encrypted** message, so anyone getting their hands on your code (us right now, for example), can easily decode any message. [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not real security.

And as I mentioned in the comments, coding for experience is good, but [don't code your own hashing or encryption mechanisms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

**Better Encryption**

Since you asked for existing alternatives: use [mcrypts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and [mcrypt_decrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php).

I think that the example from the PHP website linked above isn't all that bad. Here is another example for [how to use (somewhat insecure) encryption in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945097). It clearly separates between encrption and decryption (which the PHP website example does not), but it uses `CFB` instead of `CBC` (which is fine for that example, [but for your case `CBC` would be better](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php)).

As mentioned here in the comments as well as on the PHP website, both examples are not secure. They do not check the integrity or authenticity, and they are not protected against [padding oracle attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/how-does-a-padding-oracle-attack-work).

To prevent this, use [Encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac). Here you can find a [**description of the necessary steps for secure encryption**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26289/strongest-cryptographic-algorithm-available-in-php-5-3), and here is an [**encryption implementation** that looks ok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5093422).

**SQL injection**

Please read up on [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and how to prevent them ([use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)). Your code is (or might be) vulnerable right now. Here:

```
$drop = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='".$_GET['del']."' and username='".$user."'";
```

And also here:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO  `notes` (
[...]
```

**XSS**

You are also open to [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) here:

```
echo $string
```

See here how to [prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).

### Other

- use camelCase for function and variable names (so `CasualPassword` becomes `casualPassword`.
- consistency: either always use `$i++` in loops or `$i+=2`.
- consistency: put spaces before and after equals (`key =$separate[0];`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll keep your advises on mind :)

Comment: @Angelo sure :) Please also see my update, your encryption is not the only security issue (and not even the worst. You should really fix the sql injection and xss issues as soon as possible).

Comment: In relation to your last edit: the first query is not run if ID is not numeric and $user is escaped with addslashes(); $utente represent a SESSION which is set by the server and I thought it wasn't necessary to escape it because usernames can be only alphanumeric; and didn't think that encrypted strings with my algorithm could contain "'". Am I wrong?
Thanks for pointing out the possibility of XSS attacks, I'm fixing it right now :)

Comment: addslashes [is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339844/is-phps-addslashes-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-attack) [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes) [good](http://www.itshacked.com/344/bypassing-php-security-addslashes-while-sql-injection-attacks-is-possible.html) [enough](http://www.google.de/search?q=sql+injection+addslashes+bypass).

Comment: You might have a point with `SESSION`, I don't know how that value is set. To be save I would still use prepared statements (it's good practice to do so even if no injection is possible **right now**, who knows what other values might be added in the future).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your precious help :)
I'm going to fix all the security breaches you pointed out

Comment: @tim Could you please instruct in your answer *how* to use a library such as `mcrypt`? I cannot tell you how often I see this misused! The PHP docs are quite insufficient and lack a majority of details and topics. It would be great if you could add example code, or simply a reliable reference that does cover it properly?

Comment: @AlexL I'm not a crypto expert, so I'd rather not add example code myself. But I did update my answer to include some more explanation and links to an abstract description of good encryption as well as an example implementation that looked fine for me.

Comment: **HINT:** in php You Can use `(string)$variable` this do so php always know that the variable is a string and can't inject your code. But *always* use 2 level Security or more

Answer (score 1):

First off it looks like your trying to encrypt / decrypt a password with that code..

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

There are great functions available for encryption / decryption [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

Anyway, this is how i do it:

```
"# === WARNING ===

# Resulting cipher text has no integrity or authenticity added
# and is not protected against padding oracle attacks."

    private function setupCipher(){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

        return array(
            pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3"),
            $iv_size, 
            mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND)
        );
    } 

    public function decrypt($string){
        list($key, $iv_size) = $this->setupCipher();

        $string = base64_decode($string);
        $iv_dec = substr($string, 0, $iv_size);
        $ciphertext_dec = substr($string, $iv_size);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec), "\0");
    }

    public function encrypt($string) {
        list($key, $iv_size, $iv) = $this->setupCipher();

        $string = $iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        return trim(base64_encode($string), "\0");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll take a look to mcrypt and use your code :)

Comment: 1) Lack MAC enables padding oracles and similar attacks 2) Corrupts messages that end with a `\0` since you're using a lossy padding. Consider PKCS#7 padding. 3) Prefer `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` over `MCRYPT_RAND`.

Comment: Very good point I'll update the answer to reflect what you said there, I had to add \0 as I was getting unusual characters added to my string.